# UITableView is loading value(data from web service call) on scroll also, which should not happened

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

Senerio : I am loading data into table view using a web service call., 1 cell of the TableView contains 1 label and 1 text field

Need : on load of TableView I want to clear 4 text field's content(so that user can enter somthing). I did this using below code, but that is being called on load as well as on scroll of TableView, because of which if I enter somthing in text field, n I scroll down, the data of the text field which I entered previously is getting cleared , please suggest me how to disable the loading of data on scroll.. thanks in advance

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    BillAndUtilityPaymentTextFieldCell *billAndUtilityPaymentTextFieldCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"textFieldTableCell"];
    BillAndUtilityPaymentSelectBoxCell *billAndUtilityPaymentSelectBoxCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"selectBoxTableCell"];

    if ([[[self.paymentFieldArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] pFieldType] isEqualToString:@"TEXT_BOX"]) {
        [billAndUtilityPaymentTextFieldCell setPaymentField:[self.paymentFieldArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        if(billAndUtilityPaymentTextFieldCell.paymentField.pFieldDefaultValue == nil){
            billAndUtilityPaymentTextFieldCell.paymentField.pFieldDefaultValue = @"";
        }

        cell = billAndUtilityPaymentTextFieldCell;
    }
    else if ([[[self.paymentFieldArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] pFieldType] isEqualToString:@"SELECT_BOX"]) {
        [billAndUtilityPaymentSelectBoxCell setPaymentField:[self.paymentFieldArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        if (selectedTableCellIndex == indexPath.row) {
            [billAndUtilityPaymentSelectBoxCell setSelectionString:selectedTableCellTemporaryString];
        }

        cell = billAndUtilityPaymentSelectBoxCell;
    } else {
        cell = [UITableViewCell new];
    }
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    selectedTableCellIndex = indexPath.row;
    if ([[[self.paymentFieldArray objectAtIndex:selectedTableCellIndex] pFieldType] isEqualToString:@"SELECT_BOX"]) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"80489f70-6b22-11e3-981f-0800200c9a66" sender:self];

    } else if ([[[self.paymentFieldArray objectAtIndex:selectedTableCellIndex] pFieldType] isEqualToString:@"TEXT_BOX"]) {
        [((BillAndUtilityPaymentTextFieldCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath])setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];


        if([((BillAndUtilityPaymentTextFieldCell*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]).textField isFirstResponder]){
            if ([((BillAndUtilityPaymentTextFieldCell*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]).getPaymentFieldDataModel.pFieldReadOnly isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]]) {

            }
        }  else {
            if ([((BillAndUtilityPaymentTextFieldCell*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]).getPaymentFieldDataModel.pFieldReadOnly isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]]){
                if ([((BillAndUtilityPaymentTextFieldCell*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]).getPaymentFieldDataModel.pIsKey isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]]) {
                    NSString * paymentFieldTextFieldValue=(NSString *)((BillAndUtilityPaymentTextFieldCell*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]).getPaymentFieldTextFieldValue;

                }
            }
        }
        self.selectedRowIndexPath = indexPath;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is really ambiguous. Please simplify the problem and query to the point issue.

Comment: Refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371060/problem-reuse-cell-of-tableview-on-iphone